# How to have subforms load after the the main form in access 2010

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subforms

I have an Access 2010 database, with document information in a primary table.
I have forms that display specific document type information (credit card statements, invoices, etc.) from the table.
I have a main form, with separate subforms, each subform representing a specific document type.
I want to be able to filter from the main form, so that each document type subform displays only the documents that fall within a user-specified dollar amount range.

I'm thinking, that if I can get the sub forms to open after the main form (the reverse of this is the default order), I can set the filter in the open event of each sub form, from the main form, and get my desired results.

What I have found to cause the sub forms to open after the main form, is to remove the SourceObject from the Data tab of the Properties sheet of the sub form; and then assign the sub form name to the SourceObject property in vba in the open event of the main form.

The example I have is Me.MySubForm.Form.SourceObject = "frmSubFormName", where everything on the left is verbatim, and frmSubFormName is the name of my subform.

This isn't getting past the compiler - it's complaining about MySubForm, and unfortunately the post/blog with the example doesn't indicate what "MySubForm" is, in assigning the SourceObject property to my sub form name.

Any thoughts on this approach to the filtering?

Can anyone shed light on the syntax of setting the SourceObject; or perhaps provide another way of having the sub forms load after the main form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Form class object reference. Recommend naming the subform container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrSomething

`Me.ctrSomething.SourceObject = "frmSubFormName"`